# maxlength does not work when ngModel is changed

Tags: angular, validation, maxlength, angular2-ngmodel

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" maxlength="10"/>

@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
 name = "testtesttesttesttest"; // length = 20
}
```

It displays all the 20 chars in the input field. 
How to prevent this behaviour? Or maybe how to restrict the 'name' variable to length of 10? I don't want to have a form (FormValidation).

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnxkad?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 3):

Use **`[attr.maxlength]`**

```
<input type="text"  [attr.maxlength]="10" [(ngModel)]="name" />
```

**EDIT**

Since you want to limit it while displaying you should create your own directive with slice as follows,

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appLimitTo]',
})
export class LimitToDirective {
    @Input() limit: number;
    constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) {}
    ngOnInit() {
      const ctrl = this.ngControl.control;
      ctrl.valueChanges
        .pipe(map(v => (v || '').slice(0, this.limit)))
        .subscribe(v => ctrl.setValue(v, { emitEvent: false }));
    }
}
```

**[STACKBTLIZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eap362?file=app%2Flimit-to.directive.ts)**

Comment: you want to limit while displaying or prevent the user to enter only 10?

Comment: Both scenarios.

Comment: Yes. It works. So it can not be accomplished without using a directive. Meaning that it should be restricted in the typescript.

Comment: nope maxlength wont work in that case, you need directive